# The Mysterious Case of the Mostly-Vegetable Servo

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, servo

### Story:

I was playing around with my Uno along with a servo.

To my stupidity (or more appropriately: ignorance), I set the voltage to my servo with `analogWrite()`, rather than `servo.write()`. It worked for a bit; but once it reached it's limit, it kept trying to move, to no avail.

Realizing what I had done, I pull the power source from my Uno.

Then, I went to change the code, and tested my servo once more.

The servo's casing is transparent (there is a sticker blocking the motor and circuit; but I can see 4 of the gears).

The bottom 2 gears are ticking ever so slightly (and the top 2 even less so), resulting in the propeller to move at most 5 degrees. At this threshold, none of the mentioned gears are ticking, but something is heard (probably a whirring gear not in sight).

At this point, I would've come to the conclusion that a tooth of the third gear had broken.

However, after I pull the power plug and put it back in, it spins (backwards) into it's initial position and begins the process mentioned above again.

---

### Mystery:

Is my servo indeed broken?

What's not functioning correctly?

**Can it easily be repaired?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is my servo indeed broken?

Yes.

---

> What's not functioning correctly?

As you said, some of the gears must have shifted in some way hindering the smooth mouvement of the servo or making it simply not working correctly.

---

> Can it easily be repaired?

Well, it depends on you. Do you like repairing EXTREMELY small things? Are you skilled at that. I would say no, because it requires a lot of knowlage on the servo to be able to remove it, fix it, and not to forget, replace it into its original case. Simply buying a new one is quite cheaper and simpler.

Comment: @ Dat Hair Do----Rather than forgetting  it-  the OP could use the use the servo motor from it and make your own driver circuit for it they wanted to. They could also make a large new gearbox -if they wanted to. I dont think both of these things are difficult.

Comment: @DatHa -- I most likely won't fix it; I'm not willing to waste time (not saying that it's not useful; I'm just an ignorant teen who's got limited time to learn) learning how to fix tiny gears. However, I'll probably open it up and play around with it. Thanks for your diagnosis, though!

Comment: Very good idea. I also do that, before I throw anything to the garbage, I usualy open it to see how it works!!

Comment: P.S. check this out! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J8atdmEqZsc